# Node.js socket.io webserver provide other file than index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I started learn socket.io and use [this example of chat](http://socket.io/docs/).

When I go to `ip:8080/public/index.html`, I also need access to other files, for example other JS scripts, which will be used on client side in the browser. But when I put script load like this:

```
<script src="/js/phaser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the web server does not return it, and I need it on this handler code.

I have this code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  console.log(req.headers.referer);
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', // <--- I need here put filename which client wants it, but when I console.log to req it return HUGE data, I not found anythink usefull
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', data);
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('msg', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

Comment: You probably want to use the [Express server](http://expressjs.com/) module and then use `express.static()` to automatically serve a directory of static files with one line of code.  node.js serves no files by default so you have to explicitly add code to response to requests you want it to serve.  You can do that with special code for each incoming request you want to handle or you can serve a whole directory hierarchy of files with one block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Express static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for serving static files like your *.js files.